# Conditional increment of map stl value?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

This might be a very basic concept in stl, but i am new to c++ and so need some help here. http://www.spoj.com/problems/NY10A/ is the question i'm working with. I thought of using map stl to check for the required string. Here is my code -

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
map<string, int> create()
{
    map<string, int> m;
    m["TTT"] = m["TTH"] = m["THT"] = m["THH"] = m["HTT"] = m["HTH"] = m["HHT"] = m["HHH"] = 0;
    return m;
}
int main()
{
    freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
    int t;cin>>t;int i = 1;int j;
    while(i <= t)
    {
        char p[41];
        cin>>j;
        for(int k = 0; k < 40; ++k)
            cin>>p[k];
        char des[3];
        map<string, int> cnt = create();
        for(int k = 2; k < 40; ++k)
        {
            strncpy(des, p + (k - 2), 3);
            /*if(!strcmp(des, "HHH"))
                cnt[des] = cnt[des] + 1;
            else if(!strcmp(des, "HHT"))
                cnt[des] = cnt[des] + 1;
            else if(!strcmp(des, "HTH"))
                cnt[des] = cnt[des] + 1;
            else if(!strcmp(des, "HTT"))
                cnt[des] = cnt[des] + 1;
            else if(!strcmp(des, "THH"))
                cnt[des] = cnt[des] + 1;
            else if(!strcmp(des, "THT"))
                cnt[des] = cnt[des] + 1;
            else if(!strcmp(des, "TTH"))
                cnt[des] = cnt[des] + 1;
            else if(!strcmp(des, "TTT"))
                cnt[des] = cnt[des] + 1;*/
            cnt[des] = cnt[des] + 1;
        }
        cout<<i<<" "<<cnt["TTT"]<<" "<<cnt["TTH"]<<" "<<cnt["THT"]<<" "<<cnt["THH"]<<" "<<cnt["HTT"]<<" "<<cnt["HTH"]<<" "<<cnt["HHT"]<<" "<<cnt["HHH"]<<"\n";
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Currently my o/p for the test cases provided in the problem statement is-

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I feel quite hard to understand why the part cnt[des] = cnt[des] + 1; is not working at all. But when i uncomment the commented if else section inside the for loop, this is the o/p i get -

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 76
2 76 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 8 14 12 8 14 8 10 2
4 12 6 8 10 6 12 10 12
```

which is quite obvious though.
Please explain me the reason behind it, tell me where i'm doing wrong with the usage of map STL.

Comment: You didn't null-terminate `des` (which is also too small).  Nor `p`, for that matter.

Comment: Unless you're masochistic, use `std::string` and iostreams instead of arrays of char and `FILE *`. With (halfway reasonable use of) them, your problem would never have arisen in the first place.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - Will take care of it.

Comment: I'd suppose it is not problem with usage of map but rather missing final else of a long if-else chain. In other words - maybe none of strcmp-s matches ?